# ASP.NET - Create an Outlook template and write to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, office-automation

A form of this question has been asked and answered a gizzilion times, with the suggestion on how to prepopulate an outlook email's body and subject using the mailto: form of an anchor tag.

I definitely don't want any suggestions on that method.

What I'd like to see is some examples of Outlook automation code on the server, that creates an Outlook template file (.ost?) and binary writes it to the browser - the browser recognising the extension and firing up outlook with the template.

This is internal and the user will definitely have Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using [MSG .NET](http://www.independentsoft.com/msg/index.html) from independentSoft. Works an absolute charm.